# How to create a GKE node pool running as a service account in another project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have two GCP projects, A and B, and I want to create a cluster in project B with a node pool also in project B running as a service account in project A.

I am able to create the cluster but when I try to create the node pool I get the following error:

```
The user does not have access to service account: gke-node@project-A.iam.gserviceaccount.com. Ask a project owner to grant you the iam.serviceAccountUser role on the service account.
```

I have given project B's Kubernetes Agent Service Account (`service-<project-B-number>@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com`) the iam.serviceAccountUser role in project A for `gke-node@project-A.iam.gserviceaccount.com` but this didn't seem to work.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Have a look at https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts#attaching-different-project

Comment: this might be helpful also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67165712/how-to-create-gke-using-a-service-account-in-another-project?rq=1

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are asking for here.  Given your Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster running in Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project `B` and your service account belonging to GCP project `A`, do you want your node pool running in project `A` or project `B`?

Comment: I have clarified the question since I want also want the node pool in project B. Those links look like what I was missing! Will give it a go on Monday and report back

Comment: @GariSingh Unfortunately the `iam.disableCrossProjectServiceAccountUsage` constraint is enabled so I cannot perform these steps, but happy to mark this as correct if created as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post this community wiki answer to provide more visibility of the solution provided at the comment section. Feel free to change or expand.

As it was suggested by *@Gari Singh* you should follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts#attaching-different-project). The root cause of an issue accordingly to *@dippynark* was that the `iam.disableCrossProjectServiceAccountUsage` constraint is enabled. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts#enabling-cross-project) you can find more details.